# Is there a way in Lektor to paginate alphabetically?

Tags: pagination, lektor

I am developing a lektor-based website with numerous sub-pages, and I need to have the sub-pages listed alphabetically in the main page. This is easy enough to do, but generates a really monstrous page. Using lektor's built-in pagination works OK, but I want the pages to break on change in the first character of the list, rather than an arbitrary number of entries. I can't find much of anything in the documentation for lektor that would help me do this. I can "force feed" the sub-pages to lektor, using shell commands, but that has little appeal. Has anyone figured out how to accomplish what I'm striving for?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.